# Writing array with loop in mips assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I should translate these codes to "mips assembly" but i dont understand how can i translate the array parts of code and How can I adapt it to loops.

```
int[] numbers = {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; 

int i = 0;
while (i < 12){
 numbers[i+2] = numbers[i+1] + numbers[i];
 i++; 
}

for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++){
  System.out.println(numbers[j]); 
}
```

I understand writing loops but i can't do it when array is included.

Comment: Indexing involves pointer arithmetic and dereferencing.  Pointer arithmetic is simply addition, but when an integer array is involved, the index must be scaled by the size of int, e.g. 4 bytes.  So, a[i] ==> a + i * 4, then use a load or store at that computed address.

Comment: You can optimize away the reloads from the loop and just load the first 2 elements outside the loop.  Then it's just Fibonacci and a pointer increment to store results.